# Failed to open document. Memory full

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

This is the first time I've encounter this error. 
Already re-install the crystal report, open in other machine but still I can't open the file.
Currently using Crystal Reports 10.

"Failed to open document."

"Memory full."

[Report file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_eqA05fh8B_QmpQbHZJNjE3eE0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you need to give more information about the environment mate!

Comment: I had faced this issue in the past, more details can help me in better understanding, you mean this report opens on another machine?

Comment: @ItiTyagi what i mean is I tried to open it on other workstation but still I can't open the document